# Optimize platform independent GetTickCount()

Tags: c++, performance, datetime, linux, windows

I used this method as a platform independent tick counter. Unfortunately, it consumes ~10 % cpu time in one of my methods. Is there a faster way to solve the issue?

```
inline uint32_t GetTickCount() {
    using namespace std::chrono;
    return duration_cast<milliseconds>(steady_clock::now().time_since_epoch()).count();
}
```

Comment: Do you still have this problem when you use the platform-dependent functions?

Comment: The windows function is not even listed in the performance profiler because of the low percentage :/

Comment: On Windows platforms, it looks like `std::chrono::steady_clock::now()` uses [QueryPerformanceCounter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904(v=vs.85).aspx). A few sources ([source1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6764991/performance-impact-of-queryperformancecounter), [source2](http://www.nvidia.com/object/timer_function_performance.html)) claim that this is much slower function than `GetTickCount()`, but it offers far greater precision.

Comment: It looks like it is not just much slower, but so slow it significantly slows down other functions and thus can not be used as a simple measure for loop times.